# prevent jumping to anchor on hashchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll, anchor

I'd like to prevent jumping to an anchor on a hashchange event. I could figure out how to disable this behaviour when clicking on a link. but unfortunately, the same code doesn't work for hashchange  events. here is my code:

```
$('.parent').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this works perfectly fine
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // doesn't work
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event), the `hashchange` event is not cancellable, whereas [a `click` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) is.